# Why variable n2 is 1 when it must be 0

Tags: c, operator-precedence, bitwise-and, relational-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n1 =2147483648,num=15;
    int n2=num & n1 >0;
    printf("%d",n2);
}
```

n2=1 but it should be 0 according to me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why do you expect to see `0`?

Comment: `True` is interpreted as `1` and `15 & 1` in decimal is `1111 & 0001` bitwise which results in `0001`.

Comment: you are right, i forgot that > has higher priority than &

Comment: The precedence rules compute `num & (n1 > 0)`. If you want the result to be `0` you need to override it with `n2 = (num & n1) > 0`

Answer (score 3):

Due to the operator precedence this record

```
int n2 = num & n1 >0;
```

is equivalent to

```
int n2 = num & ( n1 >0 );
```

that is the same as

```
int n2 = num & 1;
```

So the variable `n2` is initialized by the value `1`.

Tp get the expected result you need to write

```
int n2 = ( num & n1 ) > 0;
```

because `n1` is internally is represented like (`printf( "%#x\n", n1 );` )

```
0x80000000
```